# How to separate wp_options from two WordPress while sharing post data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Does anyone know how to separate wp_options from two WordPress while sharing post data?

I’m now creating websites both personal and my company’s one using WordPress. I realized that it will be efficient if I could share post data on both websites which have different web design.

Although I’ve already tried sharing MySQL and it works, it also shared title name which stored in wp_options as well. That means if I changed site name of the personal website, it also effects company’s one. This is not only about site name but other settings in wp_options.

I also couldn't find how to do this from official WordPress website below.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, we can separate wp_options for two WordPress while sharing post data**

Install 2 website with single db ( 2 copies ).
Create new table in you'rs db. Call it **wp_options2** and copy everithing from **wp_options** inside new table
in seccond install in **wp-config.php**, before `if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ) add define( 'M7_OPTIONS_TABLE', 'wp_options2' );`
in seccond install go to wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 951 and add code:

```
if ( isset( $tables['options'] ) && defined( 'M7_OPTIONS_TABLE' ) )
                $tables['options'] = M7_OPTIONS_TABLE;
```

( these code should be added in public function tables function, before `if ( isset( $tables['users'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) ) )`

Now you should be able to change theme, plugins atc. for seccond theme, but all posts, taxonomies atc. will be dubbled in both websites ( wich is bad for seo bdw. )

if on seccond install you'll have some problems with links, add

```
define('WP_HOME','http://seccond_website.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://seccond_website.com');
```

in your wp-config.php file .....